# Confirmation link Email in JSF

Tags: jsf, email-validation

How do you make a link which you can email to users to confirm their email address is clicked in JSF? i.e. once they click on the link their account will be activated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you're already on JSF 2.0, you could grab `@ManagedProperty` and `@PostConstruct`.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Activation {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.key}")
    private String key;
    private boolean valid;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        valid = check(key); // And auto-login if valid?
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then in JSF which is accessed by http://example.com/activate.jsf?key=somelonggeneratedkey

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{activation.valid}">
   <p>Your account is successfully activated!</p>
   <p><h:link outcome="home">Go to home page</h:link></p>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{!activation.valid}">
   <p>Activation failed! Please enter your email address to try once again.</p> 
   <h:form>
       ...
   </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Quick question. The code need to be long and unique. Does java have a way to generate a long unique sequence like that BalusC? I dont think Java random number generator guarantee uniqueness

Comment: @Harry: Use [`java.util.UUID`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html): `String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`.

Comment: @BalusC, I know I am this question is almost 4 years old but please explain what `#{param.key}` means in this case? (and does it has to be `param`?)

Comment: @Buhake: http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects

Comment: @BalusC, thanks alot. Creating a web application using JSF really is a learning curve.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement it by creating a page (.jsp for ex) that has:

```
<f:view beforePhaseListener="#{userActivationController.performActivation}">
```

(this is for facelets; for jsp the attribute is just `beforePhase`). And then, in the managed bean's method use `FacesContext.getCurrentContext().getExternalContext().getParameterMap()` to obtain the request patameters and get the activation code, which is passed like:

http://yoursite.com/activate.jsp?code=54gfd54tgdgfd