# Generate activation urls in Java EE 6

Tags: java, jsf-2, activation

I'm developing a web application using Java EE 6 Web Profile. I want to e-mail a new user an activation link for his account. How should I implement this? I'm using JSF2. Is there any specification or recommended way for doing this?

Comment: Do you want how to create `key` that is required to be sent with activation URL or you want book-markable URL generation in JSF?

Comment: exactly, The user registers, and a url with a key is sent to his email like: click on http://mysite.com/activate?key=dsafadsfwe to activate your account.

Comment: May be if I could access the url from jsf and get the key parameter or something

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295245/confirmation-link-email-in-jsf

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have worked on a project that required user to confirm his email-id to activate his registration. The key generation process was like this:

**Key Creation**

1. Create a column `verification_key` in `users` table that holds *unique* validation key for a user.
2. Use [SHA256](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha256%28java.lang.String%29) hash of your *unique* user-name (email-id in this case) with salt as his password.
3. Convert the hash to [base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte[]%29) and store in `verification_key` of that user. This will be unique (for practical purposes, I wouldn't go into probability of collision).

so, bottom line, `key = Base64(Hash256(uniqueUserName+"."+password))`

......

*side note*: BTW, nothing restricts you to use password as salt. You may just create an arbitrary string on fly as salt.

**Verification**

1. Since we know the `verification_key` is unique, get the `key` from request-parameter and find the matching row.
2. If found, set `verification_key` as `null` (this will also reduce chances of collision if any) and take user to "successfully-verified page".
3. If not found, take the user to "already-activated/key-not-found/401 page".

Comment: Hi. This is a very useful answer thanks a lot. I want to know one more thing from your implementation. Once a user is activated, you shouldn't have to check again everytime he tries to do something, so should i have another table, say "pending_users" so if the user is in the user table i can asume he's activated?

Comment: `UUID.randomUUID()` may be used to generate a random number

Answer (score 1):

An activation URL evokes an impression of a software service processing a 'service'-request.

Good candidates to realize this service include servlets which will perform the user activation/validation and redirect to a JSF success-page

Comment: I have never really used servlets with jsf2 before since I have never really needed them. Can you please show me some fragment of code, please?